Zeep SOAP call with a subscription key
Trying to use zeep for a soap api call in python.
Works with usual requests but not with zeep.
Ive tried it in Postman and it work like a charm the subscription-key in the headers and no other headers
Body in postman is:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:get="http://xxxxxx" xmlns:req="http://need2code.se/req" xmlns:man="xxxxxx">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <get:Execute>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <get:request>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <get:_requests>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <get:GetAvailableStock>
                        <req:token>a valid token</req:token>
                        <req:SiteID>SE</req:SiteID>
                        <req:StockCode>article number</req:StockCode>
                    </get:GetAvailableStock>
                </get:_requests>
            </get:request>
        </get:Execute>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

import zeep

wsdl = "https://api bla bla bla"
subscription_key = xxxx
session = Session()
        session.headers = {
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,

transport = Transport(session=session)

client = zeep.Client(
      wsdl=wsdl,
      transport=transport,
        )

i need to pass this along somehow in the Client but cant figure out how.
All i can find is information is how to pass along auth and password.
request_body = {
            "request": {
                "_requests": {
                    "GetAvailableStock": {
                        "token": token,
                        "SiteID": countrycode,
                        "StockCode": articleno,
                    }
                }
            }
        }

New to SOAP or atleast when it comes to sending a sub key along. All help is much appreciated.
Made sure the url is working by testing it in postman and using requests.
